# App crashes on Android 11 after targetSdkVersion upgrade to 30 without any error logs

Tags: android, react-native

```
minSdkVersion = 25
compileSdkVersion = 29
targetSdkVersion = 30
```

It is a React Native project, and the app works well till android 10. issue persist only in android 11.

i tried updating Google WebView which was suggested in a similar issue, but it didnt work..

if anyone have a solution, please share..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this line to your app/build.gradle:

```
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.2")
```

**Edit**: Although it is resolved since react native @0.67.2

Comment: You saved my life. Although I have a native app and I had to add implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.2' without the brackets and double quotes to my app.gradle, but it worked. My app doesn't crashes anymore on Target SDK 32 when compiling with SDK 30

Answer (score 0):

My app developed old expo code which is sdk 31. We migrate to sdk 33. please check you have also available `expo-device` and `react-native-device-info`

```
1. android->build.gradle
    1. targetSdkVersion = 33
    2. compileSdkVersion = 33
    3. buildToolsVersion = ’33.0.0’


2. android->app->build.gradle
    1. compileSdkVersion safeExtGet("compileSdkVersion", 33)
    2. targetSdkVersion safeExtGet("targetSdkVersion", 33)
```

**expo-device**

```
3. node_modules/expo-device/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/device/DeviceModule.java:105
```

Replace `constants.put("deviceName", Settings.Secure.getString(mContext.getContentResolver(), "bluetooth_name”));` This line to this
`constants.put("deviceName" , “”);`

**react-native-device-info**

```
4. node_modules/react-native-device-info/android/src/main/java/com/learning/RNDeviceInfo/RNDeviceModule.java:666
```

Replace `String deviceName = Settings.Global.getString(getReactApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.DEVICE_NAME);` This line to this
 `String deviceName = “”;`

Answer (score -2):

Try to upgrade the `compileSdkVersion = 30`.

The `compileSdkVersion` should not be lower than the `targetSdkVersion`.